# How to realize the transparent popup with pure css?

Tags: html, css, svg

[image]

pure css , use background.

```css
body{
      background: linear-gradient(to left bottom, blue, red) no-repeat;
      width: 100%;
      height: 300px;
   }
  
 .content{
    position: relative;
 }
  
 .popup{
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    left: 20px;
    color: #ffffff;
    border: 1px solid #ffffff;
    padding: 10px 10px;
    z-index: 200000;
 }

.popup::after{
  display: block;
  content: ' ';
  position: absolute;
  margin: auto;
  z-index: 10;
  top: -4px;
  right: 10px;
  width: 5px;
  height: 5px;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  border-top: 1px solid #ffffff;
  border-left: 1px solid #ffffff;
  background-color: #81007F;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
    <div class="popup">test</div>
</div>
```

The content is transparent , and the triangle is transparent too . I could realize a non-transparent one , just put the background color into the triangle. While it's not reusable for other backgrounds.

In another way , I realize it with `svg` . While svg is not excellent either, cause width and height is not adaptive.

svg

```css
 body{
      background: linear-gradient(to left bottom, blue, red) no-repeat;
      width: 100%;
      height:300px;
   }
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="160 100">
    <path stroke="#ffffff" fill="none" stroke-width="1" d="M10 10 L10 100 L150 100 L150 10 L130 10 L125 0 L120 10 L10 10"/>
    <text x="20" y="30" stroke="#ffffff">
        test
    </text>
</svg>
```

Comment: Can you please post some snippet for the same?

Comment: Why is SVG not working for you? What are you going to use it for?

Comment: when I use SVG , I have to assign exact width and height , while the length of the text is not certain. In another way , SVG is not pure css .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you dont mind using `fieldset` and `legend`, you can try this

```css
body{
      background: linear-gradient(to left bottom, blue, red) no-repeat;
      width: 100%;
      height: 300px;
   }
  
 .content{
    position: relative;
 }
  
 .popup{
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    left: 20px;
    color: #ffffff;
    border: 1px solid #ffffff;
    padding: 10px 10px;
    z-index: 200000;
 }

legend{
  width: 5px;
  height: 5px;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  border-top: 1px solid #ffffff;
  border-left: 1px solid #ffffff;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
    <fieldset class="popup"><legend align="right"></legend>test</fieldset>
</div>
```